# Google Chrome - Google.com using SHA-1 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

Anytime I go to any Google site (including Youtube), I don't get that nice green HTTPS sign letting me know everything should be safe with my connection to Google. In the past week or so, it has been just showing a non-colored HTTPS, and it says that google.com is using SHA-1, which is a deprecated means of encryption. This also happens with some other sites, but most still have the green HTTPS. Any online certificate checker I go to says Google should not be using SHA-1. How do I fix this so Google can be a green HTTPS again?

Chrome 46.0.2490.80

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

[image: Here is the image of what Chrome shows.]

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Updated - How do I fix this so Google can be a green HTTPS again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this issue, I had updates off for Ubuntu so that I would not get popup notifications for updates. I just had to re-enable my sources and update libnss3 to get everything fixed up.